# Issue in If Range in VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I getting error in this line below from my code

`If Rng1.Value >= 0 And Rng2.Value <= 999999` Then

Basically I want to calculate formula only if values are greater than 0 and less than  099999.

Any help would be appriciated.

`mycal()` is function created by me to caluculate X.

```
Sub mycal()

Dim thecountX As Integer


Dim Rng1 As range, Rng2 As range
 Set Rng1 = range("C1:C25")

Set Rng2 = range("B1:B25")


If Rng1.Value >= 0 And Rng2.Value <= 999999 Then

'Here We are calculating value of X and storing in varilable "thecountX".
thecountX = (range("C10") * range("C8") - range("C9") * range("B13")) / 
                   range("C10") + range("B13")

Else
MsgBox "Give value between 0 and 999999999999"
End If
```

'Here we are displaying the value of X from variable "thecountX".
MsgBox "the count is " & thecountX

Comment: You can't compare two Ranges like that. You need to iterate through each cell if you want to know if each cell is between 0 and 999...

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the error is that `Rng1.Value` and `Rng2.Value` both return two-dimensional arrays of size (25,1). The `>=` and `<=` operators do not work on arrays.

Use this instead:

```
If WorksheetFunction.Min(Rng1) >= 0 And WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng2) <= 999999 Then
```

Or you can loop through the arrays, like this:

```
Dim thecountX As Integer
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
Dim v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant
Dim i As Long, n As Long

Set Rng1 = Range("C1:C25")
Set Rng2 = Range("B1:B25")
v1 = Rng1.Value
v2 = Rng2.Value

n = Rng1.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To n
    If v1(i, 1) < 0 Or v2(i, 1) > 999999 Then
        MsgBox "Give value between 0 and 999999999999"
        Exit For
    Else
        thecountX = (Range("C10") * Range("C8") - Range("C9") * Range("B13")) _
            / Range("C10") + Range("B13")
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't get a value from a Range. You can instead get a value of a sum (average, etc.) of the numbers in the range.
Did you want to achieve something like that:

```
Sub mycal()

Dim Rng1 As Currency
Dim Rng2 As Currency
Dim thecountX As Double

Rng1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("C1:C25"))
Rng2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B1:B25"))

If Rng1 >= 0 And Rng2 <= 999999 Then
thecountX = ((Range("C10").Value * Range("C8").Value) - (Range("C9").Value * Range("B13").Value)) / (Range("C10").Value + Range("B13").Value)
MsgBox ("The count is" & thecountX)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Of course you can get a value from a Range... but that value is an Array. Why `Sum`?